# How to get distinct rows from SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

This is my SQL table. here i want to get all

```
       marks_table
ID  STUD_ID MARKS   VERSION    VERIFICATION_ID
1      50     90       1             2
2      22     50       1             2
3      33     20       1             2
4      10     30       1             2
5      55     50       1             2
6      55     40       2             2
7      20     60       1             2
8      30     90       1             2
9      10     88       1             3
10     10     45       2             3
```

What i want is, get all the result by verification_id and version is greater values. For example ID 5,6 and 9,10 have same stud_id with different marks and there version is also diferent. I want to get max version result and all other result from that verification_id.

In CodeIgniter i have used following commands.

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('marks_table');
$this->db->where('version IN (SELECT MAX(version) FROM marks_table)',NULL,FALSE);
$this->db->where('verification_id','2');
$this->db->get();
```

What i got is only final max version

```
   marks_table
    ID  STUD_ID MARKS   VERSION    VERIFICATION_ID
    6      55     40       2             2
```

What i really want, like this

```
       marks_table
ID  STUD_ID MARKS   VERSION    VERIFICATION_ID
1      50     90       1             2
2      22     50       1             2
3      33     20       1             2
4      10     30       1             2
6      55     40       2             2
7      20     60       1             2
8      30     90       1             2
```

Comment: Have you tried ```SELECT DISTICNT(...) ....```?

Comment: Try this: SELECT DISTINCT column_name(s) FROM table_name

Comment: That won't work if you're still selecting the ID.  See the desired output.

Comment: want to help, i dont understand what you really wan((( from your question ID 5,6,9,10 DONT hasve the same stud_id, so i dont get you

Comment: I know this question is little complicated and my english is very bad... any way thanks.. And I want to search by only verification_id and max version result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First find the Max version then fetch it's data:

```
   select * from marks_table a
    where version = (select max(version) from 
                        marks_table where stud_id = a.stud_id);
```

Comment: I upvoted, but can you change the answer to say "version" instead of "version_id", as in the original question?

Comment: @srini thanks for the answer, but i need to search by VERIFICATION_ID NOT stud_id.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the srini.venigalla answer. Thanks to him.

```
  select * from marks_table a
    where version = (select max(version) from 
                        marks_table where stud_id = a.stud_id) AND VERIFICATION_ID = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to get multiple rows from table

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('marks_table');
$this->db->where('version IN (SELECT MAX(version) FROM marks_table)',NULL,FALSE);
$this->db->where('verification_id','2');
$this->db->get()->result_array();
```